# How to correctly remove an Ubuntu 20.04 repo?

Tags: apt, 20.04, cuda

The problem.
What `rm` command to run in order to use `cuda-ubuntu2004-x86_64.list` when updating apt repositories?

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   80 Aug 15 11:47 cuda.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   80 Aug 15 11:47 cuda.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  149 Aug 15 11:47 cuda-ubuntu2004-cross-linux-sbsa.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  149 Aug 15 11:47 cuda-ubuntu2004-cross-linux-sbsa.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  139 Aug 15 11:47 cuda-ubuntu2004-x86_64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  139 Aug 15 11:47 cuda-ubuntu2004-x86_64.list.save
```

The problem

Comment: consider using `ppa-purge` which will not only remove the repo from the sources, but will correctly substitute for packages that were installed from the repo.

Comment: The graphical tool "Software & Updates" allows to safely enable and disable both Ubuntu software repositories and third party PPA's.

Answer (score 7):

**Dedicated command line tools**

The safe way to add or remove software repositories using the terminal is using the command `add-apt-repository`. For example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

will add the libreoffice Fresh PPA. Using the `-r` option removes it again:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

This command is installed by default in Ubuntu.

Alternatively, to remove a ppa, you could install `ppa-purge`. Next to removing a PPA, that script will also automatically revert packages to their versions of the official Ubuntu software sources, or remove them if they are not available there. For example:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

**Manually changing `/etc/apt/sources.list`**

You can also manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` to add repositories, but then you need to know the correct syntax. See `man sources.list 5` to find information about the required format. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` alows to add entries as separate files instead of as a section in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Only files with the extension `.list` or `.sources` - which have different formats - are interpreted as individual entries. Other files are ignored. To remove a repository registered in this directory, delete its `.list` or `.sources` file.

**Graphical tool: "Software & Sources"**

Finally, also consider the graphical tool "Software & Updates". With this tool, you can enable and disable official software sources, and add, enable or disable third party PPA's using graphical dialogs. Also that tool is available by default in Ubuntu.